# Give a StoredProcedure parameter a value in Crystal Reports (No Prompt)

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I seem to be struggling here, and this doesn't seem like it should be complicated.

I have a storedprocedure as a datasource for my crystal report (14) and would like the report to define one of the parameters internally (in the report definition), When I set the default of the parameter to True (its a bit in tsql) and set it not to prompt it still does.

I don't want user intervention here, and I have my viewer as a dialog (so they couldnt enter it even if they wanted to).

Any ideas how to get what I want?

Hope I was clear!  Thanks in advance,

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could never come up with the ideal solution, and while vice's sub report would likely have done the job.  I just made sure that the parameters were set from the calling function.

Not ideal but hey I guess it works.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

I would place the stored procedure in a subreport.  Then define a booleanvariable in a formula in the main report; then pass it to the sub report in the sub report links.

The formula in the main report would read something like

```
shared booleanvar param;  
param:=true;
```

You would then pass this formula and the other variables in the sub-report links as normal.

Another approach would be to modify the parameter and click "Set Default Values".  This automatically populates the field before parameters are entered.  However I have never used this option for a report embedded in a program.